# how to create a single json string from a postgresql table with sql query

Tags: json, postgresql

how can i create a json file from a postgresql table "test4json" with sql query:

| column1 | column2 | column3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| name 1 | 0 | 10 |
| name 2 | 0 | 10 |
| name 3 | 0 | 10 |

a single json file in one row...withot CRLF such this:

{"name 1": {"column2": 0,"column3": 10},"name 2": {"column2": 0,"column3": 10},"name 3":{"column2": 0,"column3": 10}}

for the values column 1 i dont't need the name of the column !

and how can i create from the result a test4json.json file in a directory c:\test4json ?

Origin Table is

| name | x | y | width | height | pixelRatio | sdf |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| S1R1 | 0 | 0 | 20 | 10 | 1 | false |
| S1R2 | 0 | 10 | 20 | 10 | 1 | false |
| S1R3 | 0 | 20 | 20 | 10 | 1 | false |
| S1R4 | 0 | 30 | 20 | 10 | 1 | false |
| S1R5 | 0 | 40 | 20 | 10 | 1 | false |

thx

Comment: It's usually recommended to use arrays for tabular data.

Comment: It's really unclear what you are asking for. You already have successfully created a json text representing your table. Now put it into a file and save it. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Ah, I had missed the [postgresql] tag on the question. Are you saying you don't have a HTML table, but an arbitrary database table, and want to convert that to json? Have a look at https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/90482/188406

Comment: i have the tabe in postgresql, i want to create the json file from the postgresql table with a query

Comment: Please post your table definition (and sample data, if necessary) as SQL. Also show us what you tried and how the [existing Q&As](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5Bpostgres%5D%20export%20json) didn't help

Answer (score 2):

You can use `jsonb_object_agg()` for this:

```
select jsonb_object_agg(column1, to_jsonb(t) - 'column1')
from the_table t;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=fae48d9d3be5f50d63bafa6e6e108bfb)

How you save that as a JSON file depends completely on the SQL client you are using. In `psql` you could use the `\o` ("output to") meta command

Comment: if the column name are x, y, width, height, pixelRatio, sdf in this sequence and i create the json output the result sequence is random and i get {"S1R1": {"x": 0, "y": 0, "sdf": false, "width": 20, "height": 10, "pixelRatio": 1}} how can i get the origin sequence

Comment: The order of keys in a JSON value is irrelevant

Answer (score 0):

copy (select jsonb_object_agg(column1, to_jsonb(t) - 'column1')
from the_table t) to 'c:\test4json\test4json.json'; works for the output as a json file